# How to set a variable to nil if the user leaves their answer as blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby and am a bit stuck. They want us to set a variable as nil if the user leaves the question blank. Otherwise convert their answer to an integer. I came up with the following, but when I leave the answer blank, it prints 0. Could you steer me in the right direction?

```
puts "What's your favorite number?"
number = gets.chomp
if number == ' '
    number = nil
else 
    number = number.to_i
end
p number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only testing if the entered number is explicitly a single space. If you're testing for 'blankness' you probably want to [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) the input you receive and then test if it is [`empty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-empty-3F).

E.g.

```
number = gets.strip
if number.empty?
  number = nil
else
  number = number.to_i
end
```

You've tagged this with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) so I'm assuming you are considering a string to be blank if [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-blank-3F) returns true (i.e. the string is empty or consists only of whitespace. If you are using rails then you can use that `blank?` method to test the input:

```
number = gets
if number.blank?
  number = nil
else
  number = number.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra space - `if number == ' '` - this should be `if number == ''`

An alternative way would be to say `if number.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
 if number.empty?
   number = nil
 else
   number = number.to_I
 end
```

or in single line you can do like this

```
number = number.empty? ? nil : number.to_i
```